# Build a solution with an ASP.NET Core project on a build server

Tags: msbuild, asp.net-core

I have a .sln solution of multiple projects, all for the .NET Framework 4.6, nothing with .NET Core. Now I've added a new web project using ASP.NET Core, still targeting the .NET Framework 4.6. The PowerShell-based build script includes a NuGet package restore that is called like this:

```
nuget.exe restore $solutionFile -NonInteractive
```

This fails with the following message:

> MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'. C:\GitLabCI\builds\024ca24f\0\team\MyTeam\src\MyWeb\MyWeb.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: Das importierte Projekt "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" wurde nicht gefunden. Vergewissern Sie sich, dass der Pfad in der -Deklaration korrekt und die Datei auf dem Datenträger vorhanden ist. System.Management.Automation.RemoteException

A support file of MSBuild seems to be missing. I can't install the ASP.NET Core tools however because they insist on requiring the full Visual Studio 2015 IDE installed on the build server which is insane and I don't want to do that. Everything else can be installed for minimal footprint, the build tools and the framework.

If I leave out the NuGet package restore, the build fails because the assemblies are missing, obviously.

How can I install MSBuild support for ASP.NET Core 1.0 RTM without the full VS IDE?

**Update:** I copied the two directories `DotNet` and `DotNet.Web` from C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\VisualStudio\v14.0 to the build server machine. NuGet package restore worked then, but the build fails with the following message for a number of projects:

> C:\GitLabCI\builds\024ca24f\0\team\MyTeam\src\Common\Common.csproj : error MSB4057: Das Ziel "_GenerateDependencyFragmentJson" ist im Projekt nicht vorhanden.

Roughly translates as "The target '_GenerateDependencyFragmentJson' does not exist in the project." Google does not even know that word.

I am aware that blindly copying files from one machine to another is not a good thing to do, and I didn't expect this to work. At least it produces later error messages.

Comment: You have to use `dotnet restore` to restore packages

Comment: I still need NuGet restore. There's other .csproj files in the solution as well, not just ASP.NET Core alone!

Comment: @ygoe did you find a solution to that ?

Comment: @nboisvert See my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be the answer to my original question, it is an (unpleasant) answer to the problem.

Install the full Visual Studio 2015 on the build server (agent). This comes with everything that's required to deal with these projects, just like on your development machine. It just requires 9 GB of disk space and a separate licence, but hey, who said it would be convenient.