# How to build, publish ASP.NET core project using powershell for build server?

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-core, msbuild, build-server

I have a created an empty ASP.NET Core 2.2 project in Visual Studio and I manage to build it.

Now I need to build that ASP.NET project in a build server like Jenkins, which has a MSBuild plug in.

I have tried to search in Stackoverflow for a solution, but the only closest post I could get is this: [Build a solution with an ASP.NET Core project on a build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699794/build-a-solution-with-an-asp-net-core-project-on-a-build-server)

Is it possible to build ASP.NET Core project with powershell and publish wwwroot  to a specific location?

If yes, could you provide an example?

Comment: can you still run dotnet build in jenkins ?

Comment: In order to build .NET Core projects, you will have to have the .NET Core SDK installed on the build server. I’d suggest you to look at one of the _many_ examples on how to build .NET Core projects with Jenkins that you will find via Google.

Answer (score 1):

To build .NET Core (aka .NET) project on build server, I'm using `MSBuild` task with following settings:

[image]

Then, you can run below command to publish it:

```
dotnet publish $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/YourDotNetCoreProject.csproj --configuration Release
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 on my build server.